# Search for MongoDB records containing a certain string

Tags: mongodb, flask

I have a MongoDB database full of tweets that I've gathered using the tweepy API, and I want to be able to search on a web application a hashtag and it shows the tweets containing that hashtag.

Currently, I have created a list with the DB records in, and iterating through that list to display them all, but now I want to refine the search so the user can choose what they see. I have the users search saved into a variable and I have tried the following ideas, but none seem to be working.

My first idea was to just pass in the variable and hope for the best

```
def display():
    input = request.form['input']  # setting variable for user input
    # Set up Mongo Client
    client = MongoClient("mongo.user/pass")
    # Accessing database
    db = client.tweets
    # acessing a collection
    posts = db.posts

    data = list(posts.find(input))
    return render_template('results.html', posts_info=data)
```

With this, I get a TypeError, which I somewhat expected as I didn't expect it to be this easy

After some reading online, I tried using a regex.

```
def display():
    input = request.form['input']  # setting variable for user input
    # Set up Mongo Client
    client = MongoClient("mongo.user/pass")
    # Accessing database
    db = client.tweets
    # acessing a collection
    posts = db.posts

    data = list(posts.find({Tweet: {$regex: input}}))
    return render_template('results.html', posts_info=data)
```

This also didn't work so I tried to hard code the regex to see if it was the user input variable creating issues

```
def display():
    input = request.form['input']  # setting variable for user input
    # Set up Mongo Client
    client = MongoClient("mongo.user/pass")
    # Accessing database
    db = client.tweets
    # acessing a collection
    posts = db.posts

    data = list(posts.find({Tweet: {$regex: "GoT"}}))
    return render_template('results.html', posts_info=data)
```

With both these methods, I get syntax errors at the start of the regex expression, and flags the `$` before `regex`

Error message that I get reads:

```
File "pathToWebApp/webApp.py", line 71 
data = list(posts.find({Tweet: {$regex: input}})) 
                                ^ 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've never worked with MongoDB or used regexs so I'm at a complete loss here. I've scoured the mongo docs but nothing I've tried works so any help from anyone would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you provide the error message that you are receiving as well?

Comment: Edited to add error message

Comment: I have a repository which is quite similar to what you might be trying to achieve: https://github.com/dininski/ivigo-live-coding. If you take a look at `routes/post` and `database/models` you should be able to get a basic idea on how to access collections using Mongoose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of it you might need to wrap the `$regex` key in quotes as well:

```py
data = list(posts.find({Tweet: {"$regex": input}}))
```